# Two DIV's side by side in smaller DIV

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to have two DIV's side by side inside a smaller DIV with overflow:hidden;
I'd expect both DIV's to be side by side and have some of it's content hidden caused by their parent DIV which is smaller in width. Instead the last DIV moves under the other DIV even tho they both have float:left;.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="nav"> <!-- nav -->

    </div> <!-- /nav -->
    <div id="container"> <!-- container -->

    </div> <!-- /container -->
</div> <!-- /wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    float:left;
    height:960px;
    width:540px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;   
    overflow:hidden;
}

#nav {
    float:left;
    width:460px;
    height:960px;
    background-color:red;
}

#container {
    float:left;
    width:540px;
    height:960px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

This is the effect i want:

[image: Mobile UI example]

Comment: Does the #nav-div always have the same width?

Comment: No, it will have the same width as the #wrapper -60px

Comment: I've posted an image with the result i want.

Comment: Looking for something like: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lz4obse/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the two elements side-by-side, I think you have to add an additional "wrapper" element of some kind to surround your `#nav` and `#container` elements. (overflow set to auto so you can see the elements are next to each other.)

**Example:**

```css
#wrapper {
  float: left;
  height: 960px;
  width: 540px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  overflow: auto;
}
#wrap {
  width: 1000px;
}
#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 460px;
  height: 960px;
  background-color: red;
  clear:
}
#container {
  float: left;
  width: 540px;
  height: 960px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- wrapper -->
  <div id="wrap">
    <!-- some new wrapping element -->
    <div id="nav">
      <!-- nav -->

    </div>
    <!-- /nav -->
    <div id="container">
      <!-- container -->

    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /wrapper -->
```

Comment: Kinda, now the #container is moved all the way to the left and is behind the #nav.. :/

Comment: I've posted an image with the result i want.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on what I think you are looking for - Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest preventing wrapping, using `display: inline-block` on the child `<div>` elements, and using `white-space: nowrap;` on the container:

```css
#wrapper {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* prevents content wrapping to a new line */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 960px;
  background-color: red;
  /* purely to move the first element to the left,
     to show that both elements are on the same line: */
  margin-left: -200px;
}
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 960px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- wrapper -->
  <div id="nav">
    <!-- nav -->

  </div>
  <!-- /nav -->
  <div id="container">
    <!-- container -->

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</div>
<!-- /wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks but this dosen't seem to fix my problem, what i didn't mention is i want this to work in any phone browser, so the width and height of the container is adjusted with javascript based on the size of the screen and when ever the #nav is being displayed it want it to push the #container DIV to the side.

Comment: Yes; if you put two things next to each other, that will happen. So, just use `margin-left` to move the `#nav` element to the left out of the way?

Comment: I've posted an image with the result i want.